# Rails API - RSPEC Factory Girl Stack Level Too Deep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Encountering the following error and have been reading extensively on the stack level too deep error.  I am using Ruby 1.9.3-p392, Rails 4.1.4 and Rspec-core 3.1.7 and factory girl rails 4.5 for my dev environment.  I've found that some people are 'creating an infinite loop' so I've systematically commented out code to see what other errors I return, but am totally stuck.

```
1) POST /v1/notes/id saves the lat, lon, note text, note photo, recipients, and expiration
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     SystemStackError:
     stack level too deep
      # /Users/njayanty/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-   4.1.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:33
 #
 #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
 #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
 #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.

Finished in 0.52889 seconds (files took 9.32 seconds to load)
8 examples, 1 failure
```

Here's my spec:

```
describe 'POST /v1/notes/id' do
  it 'saves the lat, lon, note text, note photo, recipients, and expiration' do
    date = Time.zone.now
    devicetoken = '123abcd456xyz'
    user = create(:user, devicetoken: devicetoken)

  post '/v1/notes', {
    user_id: user.id,
    devicetoken: user.devicetoken,
    lat: 5.5,
    lon: 3.3,
    note_text: 'Hey sweetie! Just thinking about your lovely face!',
    photo_uri: 'http://www.photour/l12345.jpg',
    expiration: date,
  }.to_json, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }

  note = Note.last
  expect(response_json).to eq({ 'id' => note.id })
  expect(note.lat).to eq (5.5)
  expect(note.lon).to eq(3.3)
  expect(note_text).to eq('Hey sweetie! Just thinking about your lovely face!')
  expect(note.photo_uri).to eq('http://www.photour/l12345.jpg')
  expect(note.expiration.to_i).to eq date.to_i

  end
end
```

Here's my factories

User

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first "MyString"
    last "MyString"
    email "MyString"
    username "MyString"
    pw "MyString"
    devicetoken "MyString"
  end
end
```

Notes

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :note do
    user_id 1
    note_text "MyText"
    lat 1.5
    lon 1.5
    photo_uri "MyString"
    expiration Time.zone.now.utc
  end
end
```

Here's the controller code:

```
def note_params
  { 
    user_id: user.id,
    devicetoken: user.devicetoken,
    lat: params[:lat],
    lon: params[:lon],
    note_text: params[:note_text],
    photo_uri: params[:photo_uri],
    expiration: params[:expiration]
  }
end

def user
  User.find_or_create_by(user_id: user.id)
end
```

Here's the Note model - do I need a validation for the uniqueness of the device token here?:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :note_text, presence:true 
  validates :lat, presence: true 
  validates :lon, presence: true
  validates :expiration, presence: true

  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'user_id', class_name: 'User'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user method

```
def user
  User.find_or_create_by(user_id: user.id)
end
```

Will recurse infinitely - I assume you meant to pass the user_id from the params.

It also seems unlikely that `find_or_create_by` is the right method to use - typically if you have a user id then you'd just use `find`

Comment: Maybe i'm misunderstanding the syntax `(user_id: user.id)` does exactly what?  i'm assuming the argument should be `params[user_id]`, but that was throwing `PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer` prior to me changing it

Comment: What you wrote calls the user method recursively - it's the same as {:user_id => self.user().id}. `params[:user_id]` should work - but do check that params contains what you expect.

Comment: Also unless your user model has a user_id column, that Activerecord call would fail.